# Oracle get all combinations possibilities with recursivity

Tags: sql, oracle, recursion, combinations, factorial

I really need your help for an SQL request.

I have a table like this :

```
ID|LABEL|PRICE
1 |A    |10
2 |B    |15
3 |C    |20
4 |D    |30
5 |E    |35
```

I want to get all combinations possibilies with an sql request (or pl/sql procedure) likes this :

```
A, AB, AC, AD, AE, ABC, ABD, ABE, AC, ABCD, ABCE, ABCDE... DE, BDE, CE...
```

Each label can appear only one time, for example, ABA is not possible, i think it's like a factorial mathematical function?

I try with "start with" "connect by" but I don't understand how to correctly use it.

Do you have an idea to get this?

Thanks for your help.

Charles

Comment: did you write any code so far?

Comment: I try but I cannot get a conclusive result :-(

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this query

```
select sys_connect_by_path( label, ';' )
from table1
connect by nocycle label <> prior label
;
```

---

or this one:

```
select sys_connect_by_path( label, ';' )
from table1
connect by nocycle label > prior label
;
```

---

========== **EDIT**==========

---

To get a sum of prices, you can use a subquery factoring clause, in this way:

```
WITH abc( label, pricesum, pricelist, lastlabel) AS (    
     SELECT label, 
            price, 
            cast( price as varchar2(1000)), 
            label    
     FROM table1    
     UNION ALL    
     SELECT a.label || ';' || b.label, 
            a.price + b.price, 
            a.pricelist|| '+'||b.price , 
            b.label    
     FROM abc a    
     JOIN table1 b    
     ON b.label > a.lastlabel 
) CYCLE label SET cycle TO 1 DEFAULT 0 
SELECT * FROM abc;
```

The third column `pricelist` shows a list of all prices thar are being summed,

for example:

```
label pricesum pricelist  lastlabel
A       10     10           A   0
B       15     15           B   0
A;B     25     10+15        B   0
A;C     30     10+20        C   0
A;D     40     10+30        D   0
A;C;D   60     10+20+30     D   0
A;C;E   65     10+20+35     E   0
A;B;D;E 90     10+15+30+35  E   0
A;C;D;E 95     10+20+30+35  E   0
B;C;D;E 100    15+20+30+35  E   0
```

Comment: How i can eliminate B;A (for example) because I already have A;B and for me it's the same. In finality, each Label have a value in € and now i need the sum of each letter value.

Comment: The second query `connect by nocycle label > prior label` will give you only `A;B` without `'B;A`. The first one gives all possible combination. I can't see any  € value in the question, please edit the question and supplement the missing part or create a new question.

Comment: I edit my question to add price column.
with the second query "label > prior label" it's exactly that I need. To get the sum of the price column, I had "'0' || sys_connect_by_path(prix, '+')" in the select and I create a calc() function to interpret... I think a must easier solution exists :
select sys_connect_by_path(label, ' '), calc('0' || sys_connect_by_path(prix, '+'))
from supp
connect by nocycle label > prior label;

Comment: I've added to the answer an example of subquery factoring query that gets a sum of prices